# EF Query Not Applying Where Clause as Expected

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a query I'm using with EF6 to SQL.  It filters an entity type by a patient Id.  When I run this code, however, it contains data from other patients as well.

What am I missing?

patientId is the intended filter.

```
var res = (from p in context.ManualMetricEntries.Include("ManualMetricValues")
                       from q in p.ManualMetricValues
                       where p.PatientId == patientId &&
                       q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType || 
                       q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2
                       orderby p.EntryDate descending
                       select p).Take(readingcount).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for the unexplained downvote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is a problem of logical operator precedence. [In C# the conditional AND (&&) has precedence over the conditional OR (||)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6a71f45d.aspx), so your `where` expression is equivalent to this:

```
where (p.PatientId == patientId && q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType) ||
    q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2
```

But you actually want this:

```
where p.PatientId == patientId &&
    (q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType || q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2)
```

You have to write the parentheses explicitly to override the default precedence.

Comment: All good answers, but this one both explains and cites the reason.  Thanks!

Comment: It is worth mentioning that SQL uses the same operator precedence when it comes to OR and AND, so it's not the C# or EF problem, it's the OP problem.

Comment: @GrantH.: I've changed the link to a C# reference. I had accidentally a C reference linked. But the rules of operator precedence are the same for both languages.

Answer (score 3):

You're just missing some parentheses in your where clause:

```
var res = (from p in context.ManualMetricEntries.Include("ManualMetricValues")
                   from q in p.ManualMetricValues
                   where p.PatientId == patientId &&
                     (q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType || 
                      q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2)
                   orderby p.EntryDate descending
                   select p).Take(readingcount).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're forgetting where the implied parenthesis are.  Your where clause is written as:

```
where p.PatientId == patientId && 
q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType || 
q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2
```

Since logical ANDs take precedence over logical ORs, your statement is equivalent to

```
where (p.PatientId == patientId && q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType) ||
(q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2)
```

What you'll want to do is place the parentheses explicitly as such

```
where (p.PatientId == patientId) && 
(q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType || q.ManualMetricTypeId == readingType2)
```